# Installing a .Cab file in Vista Home

Tags: windows, installation, archiving, extract, cab

Im having a bit of a problem installing a .CAB. Does anyone here know how to?

Comment: This is in the process of being migrated to Super User where you should get a better response. Create an account and associate it with your Stack Overflow account and you'll have ownership of the question when it migrates.

Comment: @Dwayne - you'll also have to provide a bit more information, like what error messages you're seeing (if any) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Universal Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract) to extract the contents of the .CAB file and install them manually, if an installation program is included in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

A cab file is a compressed archive, like zip.

You should extract the contents of the file (double click then extract), and look for a installer (setup.msi or setup.exe etc.)